# gsub - trim a sequence of letters/numbers from the end of a word

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a list of 900 names such like these:

- miR.30a.5p.11TC.0.0.0
- miR.30a.5p.0.G.0.ag
- miR.21.5p.0.A.0.tga
- miR.30a.3p.0.TA.c.c

I am interested to know how many of miRs have "0" before the last dot in the sequence. I have tried different combinations of grep and gsub (to remove the letters/numbers from after the last dot) but I cannot work it out due to the variable length of letters after at the end. I will be very grateful for your help.

Expected output is either:

- The number of miRs with 0 before the last dot (such as this one: miR.21.5p.0.A.0.tga, but not this one: miR.30a.3p.0.TA.c.c).
- OR trimming everything that is after the last dot
- miR.30a.5p.11TC.0.0
- miR.30a.5p.0.G.0
- etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum(gsub('.*\\.(.*)\\..*','\\1',x)==0)
[1] 3
```

`.*` any number of characters and it may contain dot as well

`\\.` a literal dot

`(.*)` group of any number of characters. we will get this group back using `\\1`

`\\..*` a literal dot "the final dot" followed by any number of characters

Answer (score 1):

### example data

```
names <- c("miR.30a.5p.11TC.0.0.0", 
       "miR.30a.5p.0.G.0.ag", 
       "miR.21.5p.0.A.0.tga", 
       "miR.30a.3p.0.TA.c.c", 
       "miR.30a.5p.11TC.0.0", 
       "miR.30a.5p.0.G.0")
```

### workflow

1. Split strings by '.'
2. reverse splitted vectors
3. take second element

```
filt <- unlist(lapply(lapply(strsplit(names, ".", fixed=T), rev), "[[", 2)) == "0" # boolean vector with TRUE where 
sum(filt) # nb of files with zeros as second last element
```

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

An idea via base R,

```
sum(sapply(x, function(i){i1 <- strsplit(i, '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]]; 
                          i1[(length(i1)) - 1] == 0}))

#[1] 3
```

Or using `stringr` package,

```
#For the sum,
sum(stringr::word(x, -2, sep = '\\.') == 0)
#[1] 3

#For trimming
stringr::word(x, 1, -2, sep = '\\.')
#[1] "miR.30a.5p.11TC.0.0" "miR.30a.5p.0.G.0"    "miR.21.5p.0.A.0"   "miR.30a.3p.0.TA.c"
```

**DATA**

```
x <- c('miR.30a.5p.11TC.0.0.0', 
       'miR.30a.5p.0.G.0.ag', 
       'miR.21.5p.0.A.0.tga', 
       'miR.30a.3p.0.TA.c.c')
```